# Trouble compiling aalib on Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: c++, c, macos, compiler-errors

So I'm looking to compile aalib and aview on my Mac, both are used for converting images into acsii art.

aview requires that aalib is installed before it can be compiled

At first when I was trying to compile aalib I was receiving an error telling me that malloc.h could not be found.  After some googling I figured I could just copy malloc.h and paste it into the src folder of aalib.  This seemed to solve that problem, but now when I run the following in the aalib directory (as instructed in the README):

```
./configure
make
make install
```

I get a new error

```
Making all in src
/bin/sh ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.     
-g -O2 -I/usr/include/ncurses  -c aacurses.c gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -
I. -I. -g -O2 -I/usr/include/ncurses -c aacurses.c -o aacurses.o
aacurses.c:74:20: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _win_st'
*width = stdscr->_maxx + 1;
         ~~~~~~^
/usr/include/curses.h:322:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct 
_win_st'
typedef struct _win_st WINDOW;
               ^
aacurses.c:75:21: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _win_st'
    *height = stdscr->_maxy + 1;
              ~~~~~~^
/usr/include/curses.h:322:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct 
_win_st'
typedef struct _win_st WINDOW;
               ^
2 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [aacurses.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Honestly I'm in a bit over my head.  I'm not sure what this error means or if there is any way I can actually fix it.  Has anyone got aalib running on a mac?  Did you run into these same problems?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looking at `aacurses.c`, there is a choice between whether to include `<curses>` or `<ncurses>`, presumably due to a definition in `"config.h"`.  Perhaps the configure script picked up the wrong *curses*.  Check if `RENAMED_NCURSES` is defined in `config.h`, then comment it out or undefine it and try `make` again (without running `configure`).

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install a pre-built aalib package.  Install homebrew, then invoke `brew install aalib`.

Comment: One other thing to try is not using *curses* at all: `./configure --with-curses-driver=no`.  I found that option in a very old thread, so there's no guarantee it's still there.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help.  I did manage to install it via Homebrew.  I wasn't aware that it was on Homebrew, so that's pretty awesome.  I have another question related to aview, I don't know if you have any experience with the program itself...  When I open a .pnm with aview several of the options say "unsupported" including half-bright (dim) mode, 8-bit Acsii mode, and control characters.  Is this an issue with my terminal?  Or the actual program itself?

Comment: Actually, I have no experience with *aview* or *aalib*.  I was just helping with general troubleshooting.  It's probably a lack of ANSI support in your terminal, which I believe is detected by *ncurses*.  Try running it under `xterm`.